# Constrain to express points form a convex polygon

Tags: geometry, optimization, computational-geometry, polygons

Is there a way to characterize convexity of a polygon from the coordinate of its vertices?

In other words, is there a relation a set of points, thought as vertices of a 2d polygon, must satisfy to ensure the polygon is convex?

Only looking for references or hints.

Thanks!

Comment: Roughly speaking - each pair of consecutive points defines a vector, and all the cross products of two consecutive vectors must have the same orientation - up or down. I assume, that the polygon is represented as a sequence of vertices.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for the suggestion.